# Crystal Report Sub Report Page Break

Tags: crystal-reports

I new to Crystal Report and I've been trying to figure how to solve this sub report page break problem. I think I know what the report does but I don't know how to solve this issue.

It's hard to explain so I uploaded these pictures.

**My main report:** [image: Main Report]

**My sub report, which is in the Detail Section2 (Details b):** [image: Sub Report]

**Page 1: The sub report doesn't print but leave. It should print.** [image: Page 1: Sub Report Does not Print]

**Page 2: The content in the sub report prints. In the sub report I set the New Page After 100 Visible Records. But that doesn't solve it. I even set KeepTogether = False at the Detail Section and also the IFieldObject (Description).** [image: Content of Sub Report]

**Page 4: I skipped page 3.** [image: Content of Sub Report]

**Page 5: It should look something like this:** [image: Content of Sub Report]

to my understanding is that my sub report prints non-stop. and that's why it ruin my footer (bottom line like Page 5). So the sub report content has more records and it doesn't fit the first page, that's why it leaves the first page half blank and starts on page 2.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I found the solution for this. It took a whole working day to find this. Unchecking "KeepTogether" option in the properties does not work at all.

What you have to do is, in the main report, right click the sub report and select "Format Object", on the first tab "Common", uncheck the "Keep Object Together".

[image]