# How to remove extra spaces in main report due to subreport?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have 3 subreports and place it to a report header of my main report. So, if you come to visualize what my main report looks like, Report header A: Company header & other details of company (consume half of the page) then ReportHeaderB: 1st subreport then ReportHeaderC: 2nd subreport so on.
When the results of my 1st subreport exceeds with the space provided in my main report it leave the 1st page (half page provided) as blank then display data in 2nd page but continue to 2nd subreport and third.

Any idea?

Comment: If second subreport data doesnt fit then it starts from 2nd page..I dont think its a issue with reporting

Comment: the subreport is in details section while in mainrepoort i placed them in report header. Can i do something like if 1st page is full then display half of resultsets of subreport in 2nd page? the report doesnt look nice because of the space..

Comment: I would really like to help u, but could you please organize your question in parts such that it is clear as to what is your requirement. Just reading it once really confuses me with words such as reports, subreports, headers, pages repeating after every other word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cyrstal Report Sub Report Page Break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392664/cyrstal-report-sub-report-page-break)

Comment: Please make sure for each sub report when you right click, keep objects together checkbox might not be checked. If it is checked, then uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

From the report itself right click on the section (details) then select section expert >> then check both properties

1- Keep together

2- Suppress Blank Section (hides the blank sections)

Generally in the crystal report the suppress means hide, but it may come with conditions.